# Implicit function and polynomials

Tags: implicit-function

Can someone give me an example what is the difference between an implicit function and curve with polynomials as coordinate system?

I am learning basic math concepts and I do not understand those two concepts.

So for my homeworks I supplied this answer as polynomials and I got answer that this is an implicit function, and not the curve with polynomials as coordinate functions.

[my answer as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfPXz.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: What do you mean with "with polynomials as coordinate system"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of a curve with polynomials as its coordinate functions is:
$$
x(t) = t \quad ; \quad y(t) = t^2
$$
Curve equations of this type are called **parametric** equations, and the variable $t$ is called the parameter. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

This same curve can also be described by the equation 
$$
x^2 - y = 0
$$ 
We would say that this is the implicit equation of the curve. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_curve).